# What is the difference between these two Edit Distance Algorithm

Tags: dynamic-programming, recursion, edit-distance

[Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) is very well known problem in computer science. Came up with following algorithm after reading through CLRS but it doesn't work. Check the working algorithm below, I couldn't find why first algorithm doesn't work while second one does.

```
  public int find (String word1, String word2, int i, int j, int count) {
    if (i >= word1.length()) return  count + word2.length() - j;
    if (j >= word2.length()) return  count + word1.length() - i;

    if (dp[i][j] != -1) return dp[i][j];

    if (word1.charAt(i) == word2.charAt(j)) {
        dp[i][j] = find(word1, word2, i+1, j+1, count);
    } else {
        int replace = find(word1, word2, i+1, j+1, count + 1);
        int delete = find(word1, word2, i+1, j, count + 1);
        int insert = find(word1, word2, i, j+1, count + 1);
        
        dp[i][j] = Math.min(replace, Math.min(delete, insert));
    }

    return dp[i][j];
}
```

Notice, how I'm passing the cost of edit in method argument. Now, the algorithm which works. Here I'm not passing the edit distance in the method parameter instead of I'm adding 1 to recursive method.

```
  public int find (String word1, String word2, int i, int j) {
    if (i >= word1.length()) return  word2.length() - j;
    if (j >= word2.length()) return  word1.length() - i;

    if (dp[i][j] != -1) return dp[i][j];

    if (word1.charAt(i) == word2.charAt(j)) {
        dp[i][j]  = find(word1, word2, i+1, j+1, count);
    } else {
        int replace = find(word1, word2, i+1, j+1, count + 1);
        int delete = find(word1, word2, i+1, j, count + 1);
        int insert = find(word1, word2, i, j+1, count + 1);
        
        dp[i][j] = 1 + Math.min(replace, Math.min(delete, insert));
    }

    return dp[i][j];
}
```

I'm not able to think why first algorithm fails. Appreciate, if you can point my error in understanding.

Comment: Coding questions and requests to debug your code are off-topic here.  If you want to debug your approach, I suggest that you test it on many small random test cases, to find the smallest test case where your first approach fails; run it by hand to understand what it is doing; and see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume by "doesn't work" you mean "gives the wrong answer".

In dynamic programming, every cell in the table is supposed to represent a solution to a subproblem. In the case of edit distance, the subproblem is

- Let `dp[i][j]` be the distance between `word1.substring(i)` and `word2.substring(j)`

But in your code, the statement of the subproblem is ambiguous. The cell `dp[i][j]` contains something that depends on `count`, but which `count`? It might very well be that many different `count`s correspond to the same pair `i,j`, because you can get to it by different "routes". If that happens, your program will just use whatever `count` it encountered first, write the answer to the table and never revise it again. Therefore, if the first route you took is not the optimal one, then the result will be wrong.

Consider what happens when I give your program the words "WORD" and "SWORD". Which number will be in `dp[3][4]`? The correct program will write 0 into that cell, and eventually it will find a route that leads to the point `3,4` and has a cost of 1. Your program, on the other hand, will write the `count` of the first route it takes, which in this case will be  4. And even though it may later find a better route, it will still trust that 4, because that's what the table says.

In summary, you make a subproblem with the indices `i,j` depend on some other quantity, which violates the principles of dynamic programming. If your `dp` table had a third dimension, as in `dp[i][j][count]`, then it might have worked, because then every subproblem would be fully specified.